# Console application icon will not update

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, properties, icons

I have a console application written using Visual Studio 2010 / C#.
I added an icon through Properties -> Application Tab -> Icon and manifest.
The first time I changed the icon from the default icon it worked displaying the new icon for the .exe file.  However, when I deleted the first.ico file and went back into Properties -> Application Tab -> Icon and manifest and changed the icon to a different .ico file when I build the .exe it still keeps the old icon I originally set it to.  Also if I delete the new .ico file from the project on build the .exe gets the default icon.
I have no idea how the project still knows about the first .ico file.
Any ideas?

Comment: Additionally, if I move the .exe to any other location than:
Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Program1\Program1\bin\Debug (where visual studio outputs it by default), it displays the correct icon.

Comment: Also if I right click on it and select properties under the general tab it displays the correct icon.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried clearing the windows thumbnail cache but that did not work.
http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/clear-delete-the-thumbnail-cache-in-windows-7/

I then tried rebuilding the windows icon cache which fixed the problem.
http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/49819-icon-cache-rebuild.html

Open command prompt as an administrator and enter the following commands:

taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F
CD /d %userprofile%\AppData\Local
DEL IconCache.db /a
shutdown /r /f /t 00

This will restart your machine.

Comment: I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this, or just for one .exe icon instead of clearing the whole icon cache and having to restart.

Comment: This has been driving me insane today.  My Windows Mobile 6 device that I built the application for is doing the same thing as well.  After changing the icon the device still knows about the first icon.  To make sure i wasn't crazy, I installed the .cab on a different device and the second icon displayed properly.  Sooo frustrating.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to restart pc, in cmd just omit shutdown,  write explorer.exe, it starts and icon is refreshed... for me.
Thanks.